# Wordpress customizer: Add settings and controls dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress

In order to simplify things, I have a social icon in my WP theme, that I want to enable users to modify via the WP customizer:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'tcx_social_twitter',
    array(
        'default'    =>  'fa fa-twitter'
    )
);
$wp_customize->add_control(
    'tcx_social_twitter',
    array(
        'section'  => 'tcx_social',
        'label'    => 'Social links',
        'type'     => 'text'
    )
);
```

Then `<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'tcx_social_twitter' ); ?>` in my theme layout to show the icon to the end user. Everything works great so far.

Now I want to enable future adinistrators of my theme to add as many social icons, as they want. I believe this requires adding settings and controls dynamically, however I faild to find any information on this question in the official WP docs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @AnthonyCarbon, sorry mate. Others did it for you: https://aristath.github.io/kirki/